# Why i'm getting sqlite3.Operationalerror: near "channel_id": syntax error on my sqlite3 code?

Tags: sqlite, discord.py

Why i'm getting : Optionalerror: near "channel_id" : syntax error.

```
cursor.execute(f"""
    DELETE channel_id FROM main WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id}
""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `DELETE` to delete an entire row, so don't specify a column.

```
DELETE FROM main
       WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id};
```

Or, if you want to set the value to `NULL`, use `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE main
       SET channel_id = NULL
       WHERE guild_id = {ctx.guild.id};
```